# capitalising the first letter in a list

Tags: python, list, capitalization

I am writing a program that takes a list of student names and sorts them to create a class roll. The list of names will be given on a one line separated by a single space.

My program should work like this:

Students: Peng Ivan Alan Jodi Macy
Class Roll
Alan
Ivan
Jodi
Macy
Peng

The students' names will always be in title case (the first letter capitalised and the rest of the name in lower case), and in alphabetical order
so far I have:

```
data = input("Students: ")
print('Class Roll')
data.sort()
for s in data:
    print(s)
```

but it says that `sort` is not an attribute of `str`, so how do I do it?

Comment: Your next line is `for s in data`. What type do you believe `data` is?

Comment: did my answer help you or do you need anything else ?

Answer (score 1):

With an `input`, you get a string.

So to get a list you need to split the string:

```
data = input("Students: ")
students = data.split(' ')
result = sorted([s.title() for s in students])
```